# SigninManager is not calling AccessFailed and Lockout methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have implemented the user store in a ASP.NET Core 2 MVC application. See my implementation code below. I have set up the options in Startup, and have set `lockoutOnFailure: true` on the `PasswordSignInAsync()` method in the AccountController.

For some reason the access failed methods are not being called on the user store. And only the "GetLockoutEnabledAsync()" is being called.

The current implementation works great for regular logins. I can sign in without any problem. But when testing failed logins, I am not sure what I am missing to get it to use the lockout and failed counts correctly.

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    //...
    //AccessFailedCount, LockoutEnd, and LockoutEnabled are apart of IdentityUser
    //...
}

public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        //...
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
        //...
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //...
        services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>(a =>
        {
            //...
            a.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
            a.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = new System.TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
            a.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
        })
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<MyUser>>()
        .AddUserStore<MyUserStore>()
        .AddRoleStore<MyRoleStore>();
        //...
    }
}

public class MyUserStore : IUserStore<MyUser>, IUserRoleStore<MyUser>,
    IUserPasswordStore<MyUser>, IUserEmailStore<MyUser>, IUserLockoutStore<MyUser>
{
    //...

    #region IUserLockoutStore interface

    public async Task<DateTimeOffset?> GetLockoutEndDateAsync(MyUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot get lockout end date. User is null.");
        }
        return user.LockoutEnd;
    }

    public async Task SetLockoutEndDateAsync(MyUser user, DateTimeOffset? lockoutEnd, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot set lockout end date. User is null.");
        }

        user.LockoutEnd = lockoutEnd;
    }

    public async Task<int> IncrementAccessFailedCountAsync(MyUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot update AccessFailedCount. User is null.");
        }

        user.AccessFailedCount += 1;
        return user.AccessFailedCount;
    }

    public async Task ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(MyUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot update AccessFailedCount. User is null.");
        }

        user.AccessFailedCount = 0;
    }

    public async Task<int> GetAccessFailedCountAsync(MyUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot get AccessFailedCount. User is null.");
        }
        return user.AccessFailedCount;
    }

    public async Task<bool> GetLockoutEnabledAsync(MyUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot get LockoutEnabled. User is null.");
        }
        return user.LockoutEnabled;
    }

    public async Task SetLockoutEnabledAsync(MyUser user, bool enabled, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot set LockoutEnabled. User is null.");
        }

        user.LockoutEnabled = enabled;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I have not created custom implementations for any of the managers (SignIn, User, or Role), only the User and Role stores.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I saw it after posting the comment. What happens if you comment out the call to `AddSignInManager`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto no change when commenting out `.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<MyUser>>()`.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i will probably get rid of that line though as it seems to be redundant.

Comment: If you add a breakpoint on one of the lines where you set up Identity (those `a.Lockout....`), does it get hit at some point? [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x) show that you should be configuring those with `services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(a => a...)`, but I am not sure whether it should make a difference

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have breakpoints on each of those methods. The only one that gets hit is GetLockoutEnabledAsync, but only when I use the `result.IsLockedOut` in `AccountController.Login()` (I removed that call because I don't want an anonymous user to be able to know if another user is valid and locked out). In `services.AddIdentity` the `a` variable is of type `IdentityOptions`.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks for working on this with me the other day. I figured out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't working because of something I was doing wrong and a bug (so technically 2 things I did wrong).

- I was using a user account that didn't exist (misspelled, didn't catch it). Because the account access was handled in the baseline UserManager, I did not get clear messaging.
- I also had a mapping problem with AutoMapper, where I was not mapping the access failed count properly between the Identity user and the EF model.

To troubleshoot this, I ended up getting the Identity code from GitHub (https://github.com/aspnet/Identity) and creating "custom" classes for the SignInManager and the UserManager so I could step through the code. Then added them temporarily to the IoC container

```
    services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>(a =>
    {
        a.Password.RequiredLength = 10;
        a.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        a.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        a.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null;
        a.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        a.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
        a.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = new System.TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        a.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
    })
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddSignInManager<MySignInManager>() //<-----
        .AddUserManager<MyUserManager>() //<-----
        .AddUserStore<MyUserStore>()
        .AddRoleStore<MyRoleStore>();
```